# ACESS JSON DATA from API using Angular JS in IONIC framework

Tags: json, angularjs, api, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hello guyz I am currently developing a mobile application to get real-time covid-19 details. For this, I have used the ionic framework with angularjs. I got data from the [API](https://hpb.health.gov.lk/api/get-current-statistical/) the Data is Fetching.

Results are below. I need to get important details but I couldn't access it. I need to get local_new_cases and local_total_Cases.

How should I get it?

[This is Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifUhH.jpg).my code is showing below.home_page.ts`.here I didn't includes import modules.

'

```
export class HomePage {
  data: string;
  error: string;
  loading: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,public loadingController: LoadingController) {
    this.data = '';
    this.error = '';}
  
 async ionViewWillEnter() {'

    await this.presentLoading();

    // Load the data

    this.prepareDataRequest()

   .pipe(

      finalize(async () => {

          // Hide the loading spinner on success or error

          await this.loading.dismiss();
      })
  )
      .subscribe(
         data => {
          // Set the data to display in the template
          this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
                
        },
        err => {
          // Set the error information to display in the template
          this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
        }
      );
  }


   'async presentLoading()

 {
    // Prepare a loading controller

    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({

        message: 'Loading...''
    



});

    // Present the loading controller
  await this.loading.present();
}

  private prepareDataRequest(): Observable<object> {
    // Define the data URL
    
    //const dataUrl = 'https://api.nigelbpeck.com/';
    const dataUrl = 'https://hpb.health.gov.lk/api/get-current-statistical/';
    // Prepare the request
    return this.http.get(dataUrl);
  }

}
```

`[JSON data that i need to get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZFhA.jpg)

Comment: Just read this object data and get like this data.local_new_cases or data.local_deaths its all there. Just access it.

Comment: ok ,i tried it ,it works.